# Elastcisearch search Queries and pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in the process of Elasticsearch upgrade from 6 to 7.
These are the dependencies we have upgarded

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

with this upgrade, I have observed that search APIs are removed from elasticsearch repository.

And the Search queries we have in the application are

```
    Page<class1> c1 = ElasticSearchRepository.search(queryStringQuery(searchable).fields(fields).escape(false).analyzeWildcard(true), pageable);
   Page<class1> c1 = ElasticsearchRepository.search(BoolQueryBuilder, pageable);
```

I am planning to change them and use elasticsearchTemplate as below

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(queryStringQuery(searchable).fields(fields).escape(false).analyzeWildcard(true)).withPageable(pageable);
        NativeSearchQuery nativeSearchQuery = queryBuilder.build();
        org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.SearchHits<class1> accesscodeSearchHits = elasticsearchTemplate.search(nativeSearchQuery, class1.class);
```

I need help to get search result as `Page<class1>` not SearchHits. Not sure how to get Page as a result of search API.
I do not see queryForPage(searchQuery, getEntityClass()) methods in elasticsearchOperations class.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert `SearchHits` to `SearchPage` using `SearchHitSupport`.

Consider that `SearchPage` extends `Page`.

```java
SearchPage<Class1> searchPage = SearchHitSupport.searchPageFor(searchHits, pageable);
```